# Search by Netsuite Transaction Internal ID

Tags: javascript, portlet, netsuite

Users have requested to be able to look up certain transaction types by internal ID. I would like to either configure global search to accommodate this request, or create a portlet to handle the need.

For the portlet option, I've created a JS function that takes the transaction type from a drop down and the ID from a text box and substitutes the values into a URL, then I wish to redirect the user to that URL.

Code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9S9hL/3/

```
/* Portlet JS*/
function displayPortlet(){
    var title = "Search Transactions by ID";
    var content = "<iframe src='https://system.na1.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=10118&c=TSTDRV1179914&h=ec379d5559088dbde686&_xt=.html' style='width: 250px; height: 100px;'></iframe>";
    portlet.setTitle(title);
    portlet.setHtml(content);
} 

<!-- HTML file referenced by Portlet JS above-->
<script language='javascript'>
    function checkType(){
        var myType = document.getElementById('transType').value;
        var myID   = document.getElementById('transID').value;
        top.location.href = 'https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/'+myType+'.nl?id='+myID+'';
    }
</script>

<form method='post' action='javascript' enctype='text/plain' onsubmit='checkType(this);'>
    Type: <select name='transType'>
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value='vendbill'>Vendor Bill</option>
        <option value='vendcred'>Vendor Credit</option>
        <option value='custinvc'>Customer Invoice</option>
        <option value='custcred'>Customer Credit</option>
    </select><br/>
    ID: <input type='number' name='transID' style='width: 75%;' /><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'' />
</form>
```

Am I on the right track? Can anyone point out any flaws in my code, logic or action plan? Am I over-thinking this?

I've tried Saved Searches, but the Internal ID as a filter on Saved Searches is in dropdown format, I need a text box.  Also, the "Quick Search" portlet that exists in Netsuite does not search Internal IDs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do your users know the internal ID? Perhaps you can change the workflow so it exposes external IDs instead of internal IDs.

Comment: Our Vendor Bills and Credits usually have long identifiers, like 10-15 digits long...so instead of searching for that long number in the "Pay Bills" section to choose which bills to pay, they would rather have a shorter number to find.  So I exposed the Internal ID.  Of course, then -- inevitably, someone needs to go hunt down that transaction later, and they remember the short Internal ID, but not the actual transaction number (bill number) so -- they want to be able to search by the Internal ID.

Comment: The above code looks good, if you are only after generating the link of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks, @eliseobeltran -- The code posted should get me the link and I believe that "top.location.href" will redirect me to that URL.  I'm now finding that my form is not properly submitting inside of Netsuite...I'm getting an "ID is blank" error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used **getElementById**. To make this work you have to add **id** attribute in you input and select fields.

```
<select name='transType' id="transType">
<input type='number' name='transID' style='width: 75%;' id="transID"/>
```

Secondly instead of using top.location.href you can use these two built in Netsuite functions

nlapiResolveURL ( type , subtype , id , pagemode )

nlapiSetRedirectURL ( type , subtype , id , pagemode , parameters )

Check http://suitecoder.appspot.com/static/api.html

Comment: Thanks!  Adding id= to my two form fields made a world of difference.  Now, I observed that when I hit my submit button, I get an error in the portlet, but if I wait a few seconds, it does redirect me as I wanted it to.  Error is the same, about not having an ID.

Comment: Can I still use the NS API within my HTML?  Like `nlapiResolveURL('record',myType,myID,'view');`

Comment: Specific error text is "URL is missing the id parameter. The file could not be retrieved."  I was not able to get the two API calls working...  Updated code at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9S9hL/5/)  I just swapped which of the three lines were commented, saved, cleared cache and retired...only works with top.location, even though it gives an error in the portlet before loading the correct result.

Comment: Make sure that you are sending correct parameters to nlapiResolveURL. Please have a look at the function description on this page http://suitecoder.appspot.com/static/api.html. 

For eg. this call 
nlapiResolveURL('Record','salesOrder',41,'edit')
 returns me this string "/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?id=41&e=T" and 
top.location.href = nlapiResolveURL('Record','vendorbill',94,'edit')
redirects me to correct Vendor bill.